# Connection issue in jet service tier in jet reports

Tags: report, jet

When I tried to test the jet service tier connection it's saying **Unable to connect to Jet Service Tier. The following error was reported: Access denied.** in jet report.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community   I am using jet excel add-in. I gave host, port(7090) details when installing jet service tier along with jet report and it installed successfully. After that I tested the jet service tier connection(I selected Jet service tier option to store data source settings and and Windows Authentication option for authentication method)in setting location under App Settings. It gave success message when clicking test connection button earlier. But now it's giving unable to connect to jet service tier error when clicking test connection button.